# Can you append to two strings in the same line in ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

I want to be able to do:

```
1.9.3-p448 :018 > string1 = string2 = "substring1"
 => "substring1" 
1.9.3-p448 :019 > string1
 => "substring1" 
1.9.3-p448 :020 > string2
 => "substring1" 
1.9.3-p448 :021 > string1 += string2 += " substring2"    # HERE
 => "substring1substring1 substring2" 
1.9.3-p448 :022 > string1
 => "substring1substring1 substring2" 
1.9.3-p448 :023 > string2
 => "substring1 substring2"
```

After the `# HERE` line I would like both strings to contain `"substring1 substring2"`. Is there a **concise** way of accomplishing this?

EDIT: The motivation for this is to build a string that will contain a plaintext password in it. I want to simultaneously build a loggable string that doesn't contain the password.

EDIT2: Using @Ajedi32's advice below, I now have this. Which is okay, but certainly not that pretty.

```
command = ""
public = ""

[command, public].each {|str| str << "command_name"}
[command, public].each {|str| str << " -a a"}
[command, public].each {|str| str << " -b b"}
[command, public].each {|str| str << " -c c"}
command << " -d d"
command << " -e e"
[command, public].each {|str| str << " -f f"}
command << " -g g"
[command, public].each {|str| str << " -h h"}
[command, public].each {|str| str << " -i i"}

puts command
=> command_name -a a -b b -c c -d d -e e -f f -g g -h h -i i
puts public
=> command_name -a a -b b -c c -f f -h h -i i
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: There is no way in ruby, and neither in any of languages I know such construct would work

Comment: For your second edit, that seems more like a Code Review type question that you could post on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Explain the problem your existing code solves, and ask for advice on how to improve your code to make it more concise. (And post a link to it here, I might be interested in answering it myself.)

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/47978/pretty-way-of-keeping-sensitive-info-out-of-a-logged-command-string-in-ruby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, in your example any of the following would work:

Assignment (similar to your first line):

```
string1 = string2 += " substring2"
```

Concatenate one string, and both are updated because they are the same object:

```
string1 << " substring2"
```

OR

```
string2 << " substring2"
```

All those solutions though rely on the fact that string1 and string2 are identical in your example. If `string1` and `string2` are actually different strings and you want to append to both of them, you could try this:

```
[string1, string2].each{|str| str << " substring2"}
```

Comment: Yes, I think this may work the best. I've added, under Edit2, what my code now looks like.

Comment: For CodeGolf, `string1<<" substring2"&&string2<<" substring2"` is preferable to `[string1,string2].each{|str|str<<" substring2"}` as it's shorter.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
string1, string2=[string1, string2].map{|s| s+"substring2"}
```

Comment: I think you can do better by using map!

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
string1 = string2 += " substring2"
```

Or you need to do it exactly? I have no idea if you try to make such complex thing!

Comment: I think the idea is that string1 and string2 are different strings actually

Comment: `string1` may not be equal to `string2`